# Fullcalendar will not load events

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

We are trying to get Fullcalendar to show some events. We are getting the events from an ajax call from our DB. Then in the ajax success handler we set the array to the events property on Fullcalendar

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '/api/Bookings/' + sessionStorage.getItem("id"),
    success: function (eventsArr) {
        eventSources: [
            {
                events: eventsArr,
                color: 'blue',
                textColor: 'white'
            }
        ],
```

However the events don't show up in the calendar.

The array returned can look like the following

```
[
{
    "title": "",
    "start": "2018-01-01T01:01:01",
    "description": "fefefefef"
},
{
    "title": "",
    "start": "2018-05-15T12:03:00",
    "description": "something"
},
{
    "title": "sfse Undervisning",
    "start": "2018-05-16T12:59:00",
    "description": "something2"
},
{
    "title": "Matematik",
    "start": "2018-05-17T12:30:00",
    "description": "2+2"
},
{
    "title": "Dansk",
    "start": "2018-05-18T13:00:00",
    "description": "Vikingtiden"
},
{
    "title": "test",
    "start": "2018-05-29T00:00:00",
    "description": "sefs"
},
{
    "title": "something",
    "start": "2018-05-30T00:00:00",
    "description": "sef"
}
]
```

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/updateEvents

Comment: your code snippet above is not clear. Is this `eventSources: [
                    {
                        events: eventsArr,
                        color: 'blue',
                        textColor: 'white'
                    }
                ],` inside your "success" function or not? I can't tell, the code you've posted isn't valid by itself. Please provide some context.

Comment: But anyway why not simply specify in your calendar config: `eventSources: [
                    {
                        events: '/api/Bookings/' + sessionStorage.getItem("id"),
                        color: 'blue',
                        textColor: 'white'
                    }
                ],` ? Much simpler, no need for you to define a separate AJAX call, fullCalendar will take care of it for you. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed . The other advantage is then fullCalendar passes start and end parameters to your server so you can return only the events needed.

Comment: It is because we need the event array in another plugin as well.

Comment: ok well in that case please clarify the structure of your existing code as requested, right now it's not clear exactly what you've done. I made a mockup by filling in what I assumed would be the structure of your code, and putting in a fake JSON endpoint containing your stated data, and it works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/582/ . Presumably there is some difference with your code which you haven't shown here. It could be that your endpoint doesn't generate the JSON exactly in the way you've shown, and/or your haven't structured the code correctly.

Comment: Also did you check if there are any JavaScript or AJAX errors in your browser's console?

Comment: P.S. `contentType: 'application/json'` is redundant in your ajax options because you aren't sending any data to the server. You only need that if you're sending data and need to tell the server what format it's in.

Comment: Thanks very much, just was I was looking for!